# What was the reason for the refusal of my wife's and my request to get a USA visit visa?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals

Here is a conversation that my wife and I had with an interviewer to get a USA visit visa.

Interviewer: Why do you want to travel to the USA?

We: For a tourism purpose and to attend the graduation ceremony of our cousin.

Interviewer: When did you get married?

We: In January this year.

Interviewer: Do you have any kids?

We: No.

Interviewer: How many countries did you travel before?

My wife: None. 
Me: Malaysia, Thailand, and the UK.

Interviewer: (After two minutes) You are not qualified to get a USA visit visa.
Then she gave us a yellow card.

That's all. My question is, we had proper legal sponsor documents and applied twice this year but still got refused. My family in the USA is inviting me again and again. I'm providing information based on facts, so why did we get rejected? It's very hard to earn money and waste it by applying. My request is that they should at least tell us the reason for our rejection so that I either won't apply again or give more solid proof to resolve this issue. How can I get to know the reason for my refusal?

Kindly help me to solve this matter. Thank you!

Comment: Note that the interview is a legal formality for all US visa applicants but I'm pretty sure in most cases they've already decided what they'll do based on your application and the questions they ask don't tell you much. If you got a 214(b) refusal it means they think you are insufficiently well established in your home country to convince them that you don't plan to stay in the US.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, everything we say about a US visa refusal will be speculation because they themselves don't tell the applications exact reasons.

The broad categories have a vast number of explanations all over the web already. For example, I can already guess from the yellow paper that your refusal reason is [214(B)](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/denials.html).

> **What does a visa denial under INA section 214(b) mean?**
>
> This law applies only to nonimmigrant visa categories. If you are refused a visa under section 214(b), it means that you:
>
> Did not sufficiently demonstrate to the consular officer that you qualify for the nonimmigrant visa category you applied for; and/or
>
> Did not overcome the presumption of immigrant intent, required by law, by sufficiently demonstrating that you have strong ties to your home country that will compel you to leave the United States at the end of your temporary stay. (H-1B and L visa applicants, along with their spouse and any minor children, are excluded from this requirement.)

Comment: Everything will be guesswork, but if he applied multiple times, we can be relatively sure that the rejections are related. The OP should not reapply until his life situation changes significantly.